# Extract Yuv frames from mp4 video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, yuv

I would like to extract raw Yuv frames from an mp4 clip using ffmpeg. 
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 tells me that video format is yuv420p10le. I am using the following command to extract the frames:

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f segment  -segment_time 0.01 frames%5d.yuv

Can someone tell me please if the output data is still 10 bits? Or I need to add pixel format before output to make the frame's format the same as input?

Here is ffmpeg's log:

```
 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'clip.mp4':
 Metadata:
 major_brand     : isom
 minor_version   : 512
 compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
 encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
 Duration: 00:00:01.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 43566 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hev1 / 0x31766568), 
yuv420p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/smpte2084), 3800x2100 [SAR 1:1 DAR 
16:9], 43406 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1200k tbn, 24 tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 44100 Hz, stereo, 
fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SoundHandler
Side data:
  audio service type: main
 Stream mapping:
 Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> rawvideo (native))
 Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
 [segment @ 0x7fb30e815400] Opening 'frames00000.yuv' for writing
 Output #0, segment, to 'frames%5d.yuv':
 Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
Stream #0:0(und): Video: rawvideo (Y3[11][10] / 0xA0B3359), 
yuv420p10le, 3800x2100 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 2985984 kb/s, 24 
fps, 24 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
  encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 rawvideo
[segment @ 0x7fb30e815400] Opening 'frames00001.yuv' for writing

frame=   20 fps= 17 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:01.04 bitrate=N/A 
dup=2 drop=1 speed=0.712x    
video:607500kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global 
headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Gyan Can you please clarify what exactly you want me to share?

Comment: ffmpeg's stderr output.

Comment: It's too much info to add here. I don't know what you exactly need.

Comment: The full log. Paste it as code in the Q.

Comment: Thank you! Just added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the output is 10 bpc , as noted in this line:

`Stream #0:0(und): Video: rawvideo (Y3[11][10] / 0xA0B3359), 
yuv420p10le, 3800x2100 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 2985984 kb/s, 24 
fps, 24 tbn, 24 tbc (default)`